# is there any way to select/filter an data frame inside count/nrow functions in R?

Tags: r

Is there any way to select/filter a data frame inside `count`/`nrow` functions using `dplyr`package R?

Also, is there a way to include count of groups that have 0 rows in the output? I have tried `.drop = FALSE` inside `count()` but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you show an example, `.drop = FALSE` should work with `factor` or groups

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you @akrun, adding "factors" did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.drop` should work if the column is `factor` and there is an unused `level`.  The documentation for `?dplyr::count` gives

> .drop - For count(): if FALSE will include counts for empty groups (i.e. for levels of factors that don't exist in the data).

In the example below, 'iris' 'Species' is `factor` class, we `filter` out the 'setosa', and then use `count` with `.drop = FALSE`

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
iris %>%
     filter(Species != 'setosa') %>% 
     count(Species, .drop = FALSE)
#     Species  n
#1     setosa  0
#2 versicolor 50
#3  virginica 50
```

---

Now, we use the same `.drop` on a `character` column type

```
iris %>%
     filter(Species != 'setosa') %>% 
     mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>%
     count(Species, .drop = FALSE)
#     Species  n
#1 versicolor 50
#2  virginica 50
```

Here, there is no attribute or information regarding the missing values.  So, either we convert to `factor`

```
iris %>%
     filter(Species != 'setosa') %>% 
     mutate(Species = as.character(Species),
           Species = factor(Species, levels = levels(iris$Species))) %>%
     count(Species, .drop = FALSE)
```

or do a `complete` with the full set

```
library(tidyr)
iris %>%
     filter(Species != 'setosa') %>% 
     mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>%
     count(Species, .drop = FALSE) %>%
     complete(Species = levels(iris$Species), fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species        n
#  <chr>      <dbl>
#1 setosa         0
#2 versicolor    50
#3 virginica     50
```